# Generating public key from private key issues

Tags: c++, biginteger, bitcoin, public-key, elliptic-curve

I am using the BigIntegerLibrary and this is applying secp256k1.

Here is my function to generate the public key.

```
std::string genPublicKey(BigInteger privateKey){
    std::vector<bool> sequence = reducePointOps(privateKey);

    BigInteger s;
    BigInteger x3 = basePoint_X;
    BigInteger y3 = basePoint_Y;
    BigInteger rx, ry;
    BigInteger three(3);
    BigInteger two(2);

    for(std::vector<bool>::reverse_iterator it = sequence.rbegin(); it != sequence.rend(); ++it){
        //meaning point doubling
        if(*it == true){
            s = (((three * ((x3 * x3)%primeModulo))+a) * inverse(two*y3)) % primeModule;

            rx = (((s*s)%primeModulo)-(two * x3))% primeModulo;

            ry = (s * (x3 - rx) - y3)%primeModulo;
            //cout<<"Doubling: s="<<s<<", x="<<rx<<", y="<<ry<<endl;
        }
        //meaning point addition
        else{
            //(x2,y2) -> base point         (x1,y1)->(x3, y3) aka previously calculated point
            s = ((basePoint_Y - y3) * inverse(basePoint_X - x3))%primeModulo;


            rx = (((s*s) % primeModulo) - x3 - basePoint_X) % primeModulo;

            ry = ((s * (x3 - rx)) - y3)%primeModulo;
            //cout<<"Addition: s="<<s<<", x="<<rx<<", y="<<ry<<endl;        
        }
        //cout<<endl;

        x3=rx;
        y3=ry;

    }
    std::string x3_str = bigIntegerToString(x3);
    std::string y3_str = bigIntegerToString(y3);
    return (x3_str + y3_str);
}
```

Here is my inverse function but I took this from somewhere so I am almost positive it is correct.  Plus I have tested it and is working.

```
BigInteger inverse(BigInteger a){
    BigInteger s;
    BigInteger t;
    eea(primeModulo, a, &s, &t);
    if(t<0)
        return (t%primeModulo);
    else
        return t;
}

BigInteger eea(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, BigInteger *s, BigInteger *t){
    if(a==0){
        *s=0;
        *t=1;
        return b;
    }

    BigInteger s1;
    BigInteger t1;
    BigInteger gcd = eea(b%a, a, &s1, &t1);
    *s = t1 - (b/a) * s1;
    *t = s1;

    return gcd;
}
```

Other than that there is only my function to reduce the amount of operations to point doublings and additions.  I have worked out many examples by hand so I know the data coming out of this function is correct.

The weird thing is that I have tried this on an example in my cryptography class with values m=17 x=5 y=1 a=2 and I am getting all the values I should be getting.  I didn't code a way for the values to 'wrap around' once the inverse of the base point is reached but since with bitcoin the private key space is much much smaller than the modulo value so we shouldn't even reach that point when values start repeating themselves. I am about to cry with how frustrating this is so any help would be wonderful.

Oh also there is one other weird thing.  Here is an example when I run it.

```
Private Key:
18E14A7B6A307F426A94F8114701E7C8E774E7F9A47E2C2035DB29A206321725

My Public Key: 
458ACBDD5DE95281B9ACAB95D0F8DAC011C895EBE95E567BE9E308C12936CCAE3B81CE567B126A604A938D29ED15B5A96779AF27B5DC9ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6

Correct Public Key:
50863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6
```

It's not obvious but the last 19 hex digits are the same but the rest is different? They are the same length by the way.  Could this be something wrong with the BigInteger Library?  This was a way that seemed simple to me but would you recommend I did it a different way?